# Styling a progress bar Android

Tags: android, xml, styles, progress-bar, clip

I have a problem styling a progress bar.

Basically, I want to style the background like this:

[image]

and the progress like this:

[image]

However, the closet I can get is this: (i.e just a black border with no white line around it)

[image]

which means when the progress is set, it ends up looking like this:

[image]

which is a mess!

I am using a layer-list to try and achieve this effect, but when I try to layer my items for the progress it doesn't work, I have spent a couple of hours trying various things but i'm not closer to a solution, im sure its to do with the clip function but this is required otherwise the progress doesn't change.

My current XML is below, **note that this will show the green progress bar as it is above with only the black border and not the white outline**, when I add another item with my white outline I lose the entire progress bar!:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Define the background properties like color and border etc (RED background with 2dp black border and overlaid 1dp white border ) -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
         <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#000000" />
    </shape>

   </item>
       <!-- add our white outline over the top-->
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    </shape>

   </item>


       <!-- for the actual progress bar add our colour and border-->
  <item android:id="@android:id/progress"> 
    <clip android:gravity="left">
        <shape>  
            <solid android:color="#00FF00" />
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#000000" />       
        </shape>    
    </clip>
    </item>    

</layer-list>
```

Now, if I add the following to the bottom of the above xml I lose the entire progress bar, and I don't get the white outline as I would expect.

```
  <item android:id="@android:id/progress"> 
    <clip android:gravity="left">
        <shape>  
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FFFFFF" />       
        </shape>    
    </clip>
    </item>
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone ends up here looking for a answer, I was unable to do this in XML and had to resort to using a 9 patch image to get it to work. Once you have your head around the 9 patch image format it works quite nicely.

I used the excellent webtool:

http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html

to generate mine.

The xml was then edited like so:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <nine-patch android:src="@drawable/progressbackground" />
   </item>


    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:clipOrientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="left">
            <nine-patch android:src="@drawable/progress" />
        </clip>
    </item>


</layer-list>
```

And it worked...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do it with xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">

        <padding android:left="1dp"
            android:top="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:bottom="1dp"/>

        <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>

    </shape>
</item>
<item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">

        <padding android:left="1dp"
            android:top="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:bottom="1dp"/>

        <solid android:color="@android:color/black"/>

    </shape>
</item>
<item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">


        <solid android:color="#d4413a"/>

    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/green"/>
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/green"/>
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

</layer-list>
```